# How to make Index based trigger for openPanel using MatAutocompleteTrigger

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

[image: Sample Table View]

I have an requirement to trigger autocomplete dropdown from workItem to autocomplete dropdown activity. When user select value from workItem dropdown immediately activity dropdown should open. these is for table data. which means each row contains workItem and activity as auto complete dropdown. so based on each index of workItem same index of activity should open.

Ex: if user click [0]workItem [0]activity should open, but I am unable achieve these behavior. each and every workItem dropdown select only first activity dropdown is opening.

Please suggest me on these, Thanks in advance.

index.ts

```
  @ViewChild('workItemInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) workItemInput: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
  @ViewChild('activityInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) activityInput: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

  onWorkItemChanged(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activityInput.openPanel();
    });
  }
```

index.html

```
<input #workItemInput matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="workItem"/>

<mat-autocomplete [disableRipple]="true" #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onWorkItemChanged()">
    <mat-option [value]="item.trim()" *ngFor="let item of filteredWorkItemOptions" (click) = "checkWorkItemType();" >
        {{item}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
 
<input #activityInput matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="activity" />

<mat-autocomplete [disableRipple]="true" #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option [value]="item.trim()" *ngFor="let item of filteredActivityptions" (onSelectionChange)="onSelFunc()" (click)="checkForChange()">
        {{item}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1):

.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css'],
})
export class YourComponent {
  activityDropdownStates: boolean[] = [];

  onWorkItemChanged(index: number) {
    this.activityDropdownStates[index] = true;
  }
}
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of workItems; let i = index">
  <input #workItemInput matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [(ngModel)]="item.workItem" (ngModelChange)="onWorkItemChanged(i)" />

  <mat-autocomplete [disableRipple]="true" #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option [value]="workItem" *ngFor="let workItem of filteredWorkItemOptions">
      {{ workItem }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>

  <input
    *ngIf="activityDropdownStates[i]"
    #activityInput
    matInput
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    [(ngModel)]="item.activity"
  />

  <mat-autocomplete [disableRipple]="true" #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option [value]="activity" *ngFor="let activity of filteredActivityOptions">
      {{ activity }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</div>
```

Try something like this, with this approach, you should achieve the desired behavior where selecting a "workItem" opens the corresponding "activity" dropdown without affecting others.

Comment: Thank you. I can able to achieve the behavior but getting few issues on particular scenarios. Please help me out  
Issue 1: Because of activity input *ngIf="activityDropdownStates[i]", existing activity values are not displaying, if there is a value already for activity.
Issue 2: If there is no value for activity then its working fine as expected.
Issue 3: If there is a value then on selecting of any workItem dropdown cursor pointing to 0 index of activity dropdown only not to the respective index. Example - [0]workitem  to [0]activity,  [1]workitem  to [0]activity

Comment: Issue 2 (updated): If there is no value for activity then its working fine for first time. Again if I cleared all the values of activity and try selecting from workitem of any index, its directly pointing to 0 index of activity